# Reading and binding multiple CSV files that have different columns in R

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, tidyverse, read.csv

I would like to read in multiple CSV files that have different column numbers & names and bind them together. I know how to do this when all the files have the same number of columns, but I am struggling in this situation where column numbers differ.

I recognized a pattern in the files that would help me with my process. I basically want to skip the first 2 columns, keep the 3rd column, skip the next two, keep the next 8, and skip any following columns.

This is the function to read in all the file. I want to ignore the header because the column names are different, and I use col classes to drop the columns that I don't want. I also only specify that I want the 1-18 rows. I added the path of the csv file as a column name to identify which file it came from.

```
read_fun = function(path){
  test = read.csv(path, sep=",", header=F, fill = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("NULL",2), "character",rep("NULL",2),
                                                                                   rep("character",8), rep("NULL",5)),
                  skip = 1, nrows = 17)
  test$question = path
  test
}
```

I then use map to row bind all the files.

```
FileList = list.files(pattern = "*.csv",
                      full.names=FALSE,recursive = T)

# read_fun(allfiles[1])
combined_dat <- map_dfr(allfiles,read_fun)
```

******EDIT: I do get the combined file that I am looking for with one exception; when binding the new file, some rows (of some files) are appended to NEW columns,
This warning comes up when I run map_dfr:**

```
New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
* ...
New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
* ...
New names:
* `` -> ...9
New names:
* `` -> ...7
* `` -> ...8
* `` -> ...9
New names:
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
* `` -> ...6
* `` -> ...7
* `` -> ...8
* ...
```

**This creates about 11 more nonsense variables, making the data senseless. The row bind is not working as expected.
My suspicion is that map_dfr does not know how to deal with with this kind of data.**

I get this error when I read in files which don't have max number of columns I specified (there are 18 columns in some files, and 15 in others). This technically should not be an issue because if I specify 18 columns through col classes, it should just read in the extra columns as blanks, which is fine.

```
Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  cols = 18 != length(data) = 16
```

I'm sorry I don't know how to reproduce this problem. If you have any suggestions I would be super grateful!

Comment: It's difficult to assess without looking at the data. I would start by identifying the problem csvs and inspecting them in a text editor (if possible) to make sure they have consistent format.

Comment: Since the number of columns is not consistent, I would try reading all of the columns in with the `read.csv` statement and then selecting the desired columns with `test[ ,c(3, 6:13)]` If this is not a quick fix then try following at80's advice.

Answer (score 0):

When I have similar problems, I create index data (usually created in Excel) where the 1st column of the index data defines the names you want to give each data column, and then each subsequent column has the actual names in each of the files. I then map the file's names to the desired name to make everything consistent.

A similar approach might work for you:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(a1 = 1:2, b1 = letters[1:2], c1 = NA)
df2 <- tibble(a2 = 3:4, b2 = letters[3:4])

ref <- tibble(id = c("a", "b"), df1 = c("a1", "b1"), df2 = c("a2", "b2"))

names(df1) <- sapply(names(df1), function(x, d) ifelse(x %in% d[["df1"]], d[d[["df1"]] == x,]$id, x), d = ref)
names(df2) <- sapply(names(df2), function(x, d) ifelse(x %in% d[["df2"]], d[d[["df2"]] == x,]$id, x), d = ref)

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

This can be made a little tidyer in a function.